# For all sets $A, B$ and $C$ if $A\subseteq C$ and $B\cap C^{c} = \varnothing$, then $A\cup B \subseteq C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, solution-verification

This is the proof: For all sets $A, B$, and $C$
if $A\subseteq C$ and $B\cap C^{c} = \varnothing$, then $A\cup B \subseteq C$.

So far I've gathered some thoughts: if $B\cap C^{c} = \varnothing$, then $\varnothing\in B$ and $\varnothing\not\in C$. if $A \subseteq C$, then $\varnothing\not\in A$. So, if I'm following correctly then $\varnothing\in A\cup B$ and $A\cup B \not\subseteq C$ and the proof is false?

I'm struggling putting this into a formatted proof but I want to make sure I'm understanding it before I do so.

Comment: Notice that $B \cap C^c=\emptyset \iff B \subseteq C$

Comment: Notice that the empty set is an subset not an element of the sets...

Comment: Ahh ok I understand that better now. I can assume B is a subset of C because of that.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is an equivalent statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $B \cap C^c= \emptyset$ we know that for every $x \in B$, $x \notin C^c$. So $x \in C$. Hence $B \subseteq C$. Now, since $A,B \subseteq C$, we have that $A \cup B \subseteq C$.